# How can I access a NTFS filesystem from a live Linux CD

Tags: livecd, dsl

My Win XP SP3 registry is corrupted(my own fault) so I need to move windows/repair/system to `windows/system32/config/system`.  I have tried DSL, Sliax? and tinycore.

DSL give me a 'cannot - as readonly filesystem' So i try a chmod 777 /dev/hda1 and a `chown 777 /dev/hda1` and a `mount, -oremount, rw /mnt/hda1` none work although the remount rw does remove the readonly filesystem message but then just gives a cannot complete this operation.  I am logged on as SU.

Sliax however shows the hda1 drive but wont even mount it, 'error  *org.freedesktop.hal. device.volume.unknownfairlure*  bracket' error

I also have this error written done, can't remember what I did to cause this one,
' wrong fs type bad option bad superblock on /dev/hda1 or too many mounted filesystems
unable to remove operatrion not permitted'

So basically how do I move a file from a NTFS filesystem (Win XP) from a live CD?

Answer (score 1):

You are much better off fixing Windows with a Windows boot CD.  You can use FalconFour's Ultimate Boot CD (https://www.facebook.com/F4UBCD) or standard Windows repair CDs.

If you want to use Linux, I suggest using the latest Fedora, as it generally ships the latest software, including NTFS utilities.

You can copy the data to an NTFS partition on another drive.  It won't be corrupted, so you would not have a problem mounting it.  But I cannot guarantee you'll be able to boot from it.  There are tools to make Windows bootable, but I don't know how good they are.

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet `Ubuntu` (12.04, maybe earlier) install CD (= live CD) would do it.
Did you give it a try ?